# manyToMany does not retrieve all mapped data

Tags: java, many-to-many

Spring boot 2.5.6   (I can't mount a version)

(1) LAZY

Profil.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Table(name = "t_profil")
public class Profil {
...
...
    @ManyToMany(cascade =  {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "t_profils_fonctionnalites",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "profil_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fonctionnalite_id") }
    )
    public Set<Fonctionnalite> fonctionnalites  = new HashSet(); 
}
```

Fonctionnalite.java

```java
@jakarta.persistence.Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Table(name = "t_fonctionnalite")
public class Fonctionnalite {
...
...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "fonctionnalites", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Profil> profils   = new HashSet();
```

I launch the project, the intermediate table is created: "t_profils_fonctionnalites"
I insert data into this table :

```
profil fonctionnalite
1         1
1         2
2         1
2         4
```

controller

```java
...
...
List<Profil> profilList= profilDao.findAll();
profilList.forEach(profil -> { profil.getFonctionnalites(); });
return new ResponseEntity<>(profilList, HttpStatus.OK);
```

I get this data with postman :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "CODEP1",
        "label": "defaut",
        "description": "defaut description1",
        "fonctionnalites": []    <---------   no fonctionnalites data  
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "CODEP2",
        "label": "label2",
        "description": "description2",
        "fonctionnalites": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "code": "codeF1",
                "label": "labelF1",
                "description": "descriptionF1",
                "profils": []
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "code": "codeF4",
                "label": "labelF4",
                "description": "descriptionF4",
                "profils": []
            }
        ]        
    },
```

"fonctionnalites for profil id = 1 is empty !   why ?

(2)
I put the fetch in EAGER on Profil :

Profil.java

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade =  {
            CascadeType.ALL,
        }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "t_profil_fonctionnalite",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "profil_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fonctionnalite_id") }
    )
    public Set<Fonctionnalite> fonctionnalites  = new HashSet();
```

This time I get different data, some profiles have features. sometimes just one when there are 2.

I do not understand what is going on. Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't repost the same question

Answer (score 0):

Why this code snippet is needed? `profilList.forEach(profil -> { profil.getFonctionnalites(); });`

Can you try this:

```
...
...
List<Profil> profilList= profilDao.findAll();
return new ResponseEntity<>(profilList, HttpStatus.OK);
```